# Functional Dependencies Query

Tags: dependencies, database-normalization

I am having a confusion in Functional Dependencies

I have a relation R(A,B,C,D,E,F) Where {A, B} is the key

And the FD set I have is {A->FC, C->D, B->E}

What Normal Form is it in?

Basically I want easy explanation. For a relation to be in 2NF, it must not have partial dependency, so as B is determining E is it not in 2NF, which means it is in 1NF?

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is right.

AB is the only candidate key in R. Keep in mind that normalization considers *all* the candidate keys, not just the primary key. In your case, there's only one candidate key, but relations having multiple candidate keys are common.

B->E is a partial-key dependency; so is A->FC. Therefore, R is not in 2NF.

Since R is not in 2NF, it must be in 1NF or lower. There isn't any normal form lower than 1NF, so R is in 1NF.

Comment: how'd we split this up into 2NF? {A, B} {A, C, D, F} and {B, E} would be the split relations?

Comment: {ACF}, {CD}, {BE}. There's a transitive dependency: A->C, C->D.